# Changing an array to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

My question is it possible to change and array into an object?

The following code counts the number of occurrences of each word in an array.

```
// function for getting the frequency of each word within a string
function getFreqword(){
  var string = tweettxt.toString(), // turn the array into a string
      changedString = string.replace(/,/g, " "), // remove the array elements 
      split = changedString.split(" "), // split the string 
      words = []; 

  for (var i=0; i<split.length; i++){
    if(words[split[i]]===undefined){
      words[split[i]]=1;
    } else {
      words[split[i]]++;
    }
  }
  return words;
}
```

Is it possible to change it so that instead of returning an array like this:

```
[ Not: 1,
  long: 1,
  left: 2,
  grab: 1,
  an: 4,
  Easter: 5,
  bargain: 1,]
```

instead it returns an object like this? `{ word: 'Not' num: 1 }` etc.

Comment: You can assign object properties with bracket notation. `var obj = {};` then dot notation add a property `obj.prop1 = 2;` or bracket notation like `obj["prop2"] = 2;` the handy thing is that bracket notation can use a string thus `var propName = "prop3"` then `obj[propName] = 2;` giving `obj.prop3 === 2` as true.

Comment: I suppose what you really want is an array of objects : [ { word: 'Not', num: 1 }, { word: 'long', num: 1 }, ... ] rather than a single object.

Comment: @Andy tweetxt is and array that is then turned into a string that can be sorted

Comment: @Arnauld If I can sort that array by the num element of the object then yes.

Comment: @cockmagic, can you show the initial `tweetxt` value ?

Comment: Yes. Using the variable 'array' from Nina answer, you can do `array.sort(function(a, b) { return a.num < b.num; });`

Comment: Ah, ok. ref: `tweettxt.join(' ').replace(/,/g, '').split(' ')` will cover those first three lines.

Comment: `[ Not: 1, long: 1, ... ]` is not a valid JS array. Did you mean `{ Not: 1, long: 1, ... }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.key()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/key) and [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for converting an object into an array of objects.

```js
var obj = { Not: 1, long: 1, left: 2, grab: 1, an: 4, Easter: 5, bargain: 1 },
    array = Object.keys(obj).map(function (k) { return { word: k, num: obj[k] }; });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// edit sorting

array.sort(function (a, b) { return a.num - b.num; });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```